# Auto scroll down to bottom of a dynamically generated div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm kind of running out of ideas on how to make this work. The code is:

```
$('#inboxArea').on('click', '.readMessage', function(){
var tix_id = $(this).data('id');
var tix_sub = $(this).data('sub');
var tix_date = $(this).data('date');

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'user/messages/'+tix_id+'/'+tix_sub+'/'+tix_date,
    success: function(data){
        $('#inboxArea').html(data);
    }
});
$('#msgScroll').animate({ scrollTop: $('#msgScroll')[0].scrollHeight}, 500);
```

});

What supposed to happen is when you click `.readMessage`it's supposed to put up a series of div's unto `#inboxArea` via ajax. I sort of want the div named `#msgScroll` to auto scroll down afterwards. The problem is, `#msgScroll` is a part of what's going to be inserted unto `#inboxArea` with this function.

If it helps, this is what's supposed to be inserted to `#inboxArea` notice that `#msgScroll` is on there.

```
<button id="msgBack">Back</button>
    <h3>Inbox</h3>
    <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-9">'.$sub.'</div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">'.$date.'</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body scroll" id="msgScroll">
                <div id="msgBody">';
    foreach($messages as $message){
                echo '
                    <p>From: '.$message->name.'</p>
                    <p>Message: '.$message->message.'</p>
                    <hr>';
    }
            echo'
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="msgReply" placeholder="Reply..." name="message" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <button id="msgSendReply" data-tid="'.$id.'">Send Reply</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `msgScroll` will be populate by the `$.ajax()` function, move `animate()` in the success callback handler

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#inboxArea').html(data);
    $('#msgScroll').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#msgScroll')[0].scrollHeight
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: Oohhhh that worked out perfectly. Didn't really thought about that. Thanks a lot!